# What is the difference between defaults and context options in file.managed salt state?

Tags: salt-stack

State `file.managed` [has](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.managed) `defaults` and `context` options for template rendering. Both provide context for template vars.
What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`defaults` are the fallback default values that will be passed to the template in case `context` doesn't have a proper value. If `context` has a value - it will override `default`. E.g:

```
/etc/myconfig.cfg:
   - file.managed:
     - source: salt://myconfig.tmpl
     - template: jinja
     - defaults:
       foo: bar
     - context:
       foo: baz
```

In this case value of `foo` will always be `baz`. Generally `context` is used when you need to have conditional values. E.g.:

```
/etc/myconfig.cfg:
   - file.managed:
     - source: salt://myconfig.tmpl
     - template: jinja
     - defaults:
       foo: bar
     {% if salt[grains.get]("os") == 'Debian' %}
     - context:
       foo: baz
     {% endif %}
```

In this case every non-Debian system will end-up having value `bar`, while Debian will have `baz` in the template.

Comment: OK. But the same can be archived just with a simple `else`.

Comment: Yes, that's true. It's mostly a matter of what is more convenient for you and your team. In `salt` there are few other places where you have more than one option to perform the same action like `watch` vs `watch_in`

Comment: I never understood this two parameters, and still don't, because as said by @Raz you can also do it with only one. Nevermind I'll continue to ignore one of them :)